# Reading Multiple Resultset using JPA

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jpa, eclipselink

I am using JPA(Eclipselink) to execute SQL Server Stored Procedure which returns multiple Resultsets.

As per my knowledge, easiest way to call a SP is:

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery("exec sp_name").getResultList();
```

After executing the SP I can only read the single (or very first) `ResultSet`.

Can some one please suggest how do I retrieve the next ResultSets (or ResultLists())?

Comment: What do you mean with "multiple ResultSets"? Lines? Or your procedure makes more than one select?

Comment: @Renan: SQLServer SP's can return multiple results sets.

Comment: @Renan: Yes multiple selects.

Answer (score 3):

I can't answer for EclipseLink specifically, and I'm not sure what the JPA spec says, but most features of JPA took their cue from Hibernate, and Hibernate's [limitations on stored procedures](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#querysql-limits-storedprocedures) are:

> The procedure must return a result set. Note that since these servers can return multiple result sets and update counts, Hibernate will iterate the results and take the first result that is a result set as its return value. Everything else will be discarded.

My guess is that JPA defines the same limitation.

Answer (score 2):

EclipseLink has extended support for stored procedures through its StoreProcedureCall class and NamedStoredProcedureCallQuery annotation.  You can create a JPA Query using a StoredProcedureCall using the JpaEntityManager interface createQuery(Call) API.

StoreProcedureCall provides additional support over JPA native SQL queries including support for in, out and intout parameters and cursored output parameters and typing.  StoreProcedureCall supports calls with both a result set and output parameters, but does not currently support multiple result sets.

What is being returned in your second result set, and how do you want the result returned?  You could subclass and customize your SQLServerPlatform in EclipseLink and overwrite the executeStoredProcedure() method to process multiple results sets.  It should not be to hard, and you could contribute the code back to EclipseLink if successful.  Or you could log and enhancement request for this feature.  Looking at the code it should be simple enough to implement, the bigger issue is how to return the multiple result sets.